# Typescript: passing function as type in interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am trying to figure out how to get type out of existing Typescript function and use it to define interface. I am working on React project and I want to pass `action creator` (function) to `Props` interface and then into React Component as `Component<Props, State>`.

Example action creator:

```
export function myFunction(foo: string = "bar") {
    return {
        type: "EXAMPLE_ACTION",
        payload: foo,
    }
}
```

Example component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { myFunction } from "actions"

export interface Props {
    // This is what I'm trying to and and it ends up in ts error
    myFunc: myFunction
}

class SomeComponent extends Component<Props, {}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Example:
                <button onClick={this.props.myFunc("baz")}>Click to dispatch</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(null, {
    myFunction
})(SomeComponent)
```

I was thinking this could work, but frankly it's a typescript error:

`[ts] Cannot find name 'myFunction'`

I was wondering if i have to define a separate `type` to pass it to my component, something like this:

```
export type myFuncType = (foo: string) => { type: string, payload: string }
export const myFunction: myFuncType = (foo: string) => {
    return {
        type: "EXAMPLE_ACTION",
        payload: foo,
    }
}
```

but that seems too verbose and redundant and would need to import another export. Is there any other way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `typeof` keyword in *type position* to obtain the type of a named value.

In this case you would write

```
import { myFunction } from "actions";

export interface Props {
    myFunc: typeof myFunction;
}
```

The reason you currently receive an error is that TypeScript has two distinct declaration spaces, one for values and one for types. `function` defines a value but not a type.

Comment: Ah thanks, works great. Somehow I didn't even think about that